# Zend _forward calling init twice

Tags: php, zend-framework, forward

So i have a controller with an `init` function that sets the title of the page with `headMeta->appendName` then later on an error catch i want to forward to another page, but not the error controller, but another action on the same controller, hence calling the init twice, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Zend_Registry` as a flag to check if the meta tag is set or not

```
public function init()
{
   if(!Zend_Registry::isRegistered('headMetaSet'))
   {
    $this->view->headMeta()->appendName('keywords', 'keys');
    Zend_Registry::set('headMetaSet', true);
   }
}
```